# C# using statement rejected in one class but accepted in another in same project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF desktop project targeting .Net 4.5.1.
Two identical using statements (verified by cut and paste):

```
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

The definitions are accepted in one class but rejected in another. **The type or namespace 'Data' does not exist in namespace 'System.Windows'**

- Both classes are in the same project.
- Both classes are in the same namespace.
- They are in different folders within the project structure.
- I have project references to both PresentationCore and
  PresentationFramework.
- The project is targeting Mixed Platforms/ Any CPU

The one working is:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Data; 
using System.Windows.Controls; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
using PO.Model; 

namespace PO 
{ 
    public partial class frmPOOrders : Window
```

while the broken one is:

```
using System; 
using System.Windows; 
using System.Windows.Data; 
using System.Windows.Controls; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Windows.Input; 
using System.Data; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Globalization; 
using System.Windows.Markup; 

namespace PO 
{ 
    /// See: hardcodet.net/2008/04/wpf-custom-binding-class
    /// </summary> 
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))] 
    public abstract class BindingDecoratorBase : MarkupExtension
```

Comment: Are they inside or outside the `namespace YourNamespace {` declaration?

Comment: can you show us part of both classes and your usings?

Comment: using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using PO.Model;

namespace PO
{
 public partial class frmPOOrders : Window

Comment: And :using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace PO
{
    /// See: http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/04/wpf-custom-binding-class 
    /// </summary>
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
    public abstract class BindingDecoratorBase : MarkupExtension

Comment: It is the second one which is broken. Interestingly, the 'using System.Windows.Markup;' is accepted, but the MarkupExtension type is not found - even though it is in this namespace.

Comment: @user Right click on both files, *Properties* and check that the Build Action is set to *Compile*.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. I had the same file in a sub-project which got left behind during refactoring. When I deleted that file the using errors disappeared. That file was identical so the using compiler errors were totally misleading.